# Minimize enclosing perimeter subject to minimum distance between nodes

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, computational-geometry

I have a collection of nodes $N_i$ and minimum distances $d_{i,j}$ between them like this (not all $d_{i,j}$ shown for visual clarity).

[image: example]

The task is to find a 2D graph (the (x,y) positions of each node) such that the enclosing perimeter (border of red polygon) is as small as possible subject to the distances between the nodes being not smaller than $d_{i,j}$. Is there an algorithm to solve this problem??

Comment: the word planar is misleading here, you are not demanding that a set of edges  meet only at endpoints.....my first guess is a dynamic geometry approach...Well, see answers by one guy   https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:237+[computational-geometry]  in area https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-geometry

Comment: Thanks Will, with "planar" I ment to say I look for a 2D solution, I changed that and added computational-geometry instead

Comment: It is often called a [geometric graph](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-39286-3_17)

Comment: You can place all vertices to a line getting zero area. Just place each point on a big enough distance from the others. Even if we forbid making 3 collinear vertices, it would be still possible to make the figure arbitrarily thin remaining within a constant bound on its length, so the area would be arbitrarily close to zero. Didn't you miss any other restriction?

Comment: Good point @Smylic , what I want is the "smallest" figure and I thought that area would be a good metric, but know I believe that the perimeter would be a better choice

Comment: Are you interested about getting a specific algorithm, or about getting solutions of instances of this problem? In the second case, you might as well write the problem as a QCQP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program) and send it to a solver.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni I was hoping more of a general solution, but I like your proposal: How can this problem be formulated as QCQP? The constraints are clear for me but what would be the objective function? Only the nodes on the outside define the distance of the perimeter but those nodes are not fixed a priori

Comment: @KenGrimes You are right, the objective function is troublesome. Hum.... I'll think about it and hopefully write an answer.

Comment: After trying to solve your problem, I had to give up due to matters of time: however, if I am allowed to give you a suggestion, have a look at Donald Knuth "[Axioms and hulls](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/aah.html)". The book explains how to find the convex hull of a given set in the plane: perhaps implementing the algorithm described there and using the simplex algorithm may led you to the sought for solution(s). Good luck.

Comment: @KenGrimes I could not find a QCQP model. Due to the fact that perimeter nodes are not known in advance, one has to use binary variables $u_{ij}$ stating that $ij$ is a segment on the perimeter. These variables multiply other expressions, which makes the model at least cubic. So it is probably not worth trying.

Comment: @KenGrimes One thing that usually works not bad, and is (comparatively) simple (i.e. simpler than devising a totally ad hoc and deterministic algorithm), is local search. The idea is to progressively refine a solution by small steps. The steps can be atomic (e.g. modifying one node positon), or some combination of a few atomic steps. You may allow steps that temporarily break some constraints or downgrade the solution, especially coupled with simulated annealing. A good property of local search is that it is easily parallelized.